# Accsing an API from console is working but same is not working with MVC web

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, console-application, blockcypher

I am trying to access BlockCypher from console Application which works absolutely fine. But when i am trying to access the same MVC Web Application, I am not getting the response from "BlockCypher". not sure why. 
here is the link i am following:

[BlockCypher git](https://github.com/blockcypher/node-client)

here is the code i am using

```
  Blockcypher objmain = new Blockcypher("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", Endpoint.BcyTest);

        objmain.GenerateAddress().Wait();
```

please help, any idea what i am doing wrong in web.? or what i am missing.

Comment: Show us your entire action's code, not just this bit. It should be async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be hitting a deadlock, instead of using `Wait()` in a synchronous context, instead make your action / parent code async and use `await`.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyAction()
{
    var bc = new Blockcypher("..", Endpoint.BcyTest);
    await bc.GenerateAddress();

    // ..
}
```